# An application of Green theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

Greens theorem states:
$$ \oint_C P dx + Q dy = \int \int_D (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}) dxdy $$

I have to calculate: $\oint_γ x y^2 dx + (x+y) dy$ in the domain:

[image]

We have $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=2xy.$ I think that I have to split the double integral into three double integrals. For example, the first double integral would have bounds $-2 \le x \le -1$ and $ \sqrt{1-x^2} \le y \le \sqrt{4-x^2}.$ Am I right? I am not sure for the bounds of the other two double integrals. Any particular help please?

Comment: You are correct in that you will have to break up the region into 3 double integrals. I think one double integral should cover the region from -$2$ $\le$ x $\le$ $0$ (Hint: Use polar coordinates). Another double integral will cover the region from $0$ $\le$ x $\le$ 1 (integrated from $y=1$ to the circle of radius 2, polar coordinates will probably be useful here too). The final double integral will cover the region from $1$ $\le$ x $\le$ 2  (with the bounds being what?)

Comment: I think I would write it as difference of integrals.  The integral over the big semicircle, minus the integral over the little semi circle, minus the integral over a curvilinear triangle. Polar coordinates look promising.

Comment: I was in mind about difference of integrals, could you write the bounds of them?

Comment: @George Which of them do you have trouble with?  The first two are easy right?  The third is $$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{1-x^2}}^1f(x,y)\,\mathrm{dy\,dx}$$

Comment: $f(x,y)=1-2xy?$ Could you write the other two? It would be very helpful, thank you

Comment: You could also integrate over the entire semicircle $x^2 + y^2 < 4$ with $y > 0$ and then subtract off the quarter circle $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ with $y >0$ and $x < 0$ along with the square $x,y \in (0,1).$ In my opinion, this is easiest.

Answer (score 1):

As @saulspatz suggested . The first region is the big half circle 
$-2\leq x\leq 2, 0\leq y\leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$ minus the second region is the small half circle $-1\leq x\leq1, 0\leq y\leq\sqrt{1-x^2}$ minus the third region $0\leq x\leq 1, \sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq 1$. The idea to find the limit is to check from where to where $y$ changes as a function of $x$ then you made a projection at the x-axis to see the limits of $x$. So in your answer you are wrong because if you take $y$ changing from the big semi to small semi that region projection on the x-axis  is from $-1$ to $1$ . And the region above $-2\leq x\leq -1$ is $0\leq y\leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: $f(x,y)=1-2xy$ for the three integrals?

Comment: @George yeah it is